# How to prevent additional table creation

Tags: javascript

I've been looking for workarounds to ensure that only one table is created. So far the only one i have come up with is to disable the button after it had been pressed. Here is my code:

```
    function bikeData() {
        // Select the Table
        var tbl = document.getElementById('bikeInnerTable');
        var th = document.getElementById('tableHead_B');
        var headerText = ["ID", "Bike Status", "Bike Location", "Depot ID"];
        // Set number of rows
        var rows = 10;
        // Set number of columns
        var columns = headerText.length;

        // create table header
        for (var h = 0; h < columns; h++) {
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            td.innerText = headerText[h];            
            th.appendChild(td);
        }

        // create table data
        for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) { 
            var cellText = ["UNDEFINED", "UNDEFINED", "UNDEFINED", "UNDEFINED"];

            // generate ID
            x = getRandomNumber(1000, 1);
            cellText[0] = x;
            // generate Status
            x = getStatus();
            cellText[1] = x;
            // generate Name
            x = getLocation();
            cellText[2] = x;
            // generate depot ID
            x = getRandomNumber(1000, 1);
            cellText[3] = x;


            var tr = document.getElementById("b_row" + r);
            for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++) 
            {
                var td = document.createElement("td");        
                td.innerText = cellText[c];
                tr.appendChild(td);                                    
            }
        }

}
```

If the button is pressed multiple times then the table is created multiple times. However how can I adapt the code to ensure that it if the table is already present within the div, then it doesn't continue in creating the table additional times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a flag and then only execute the code when applicable.

```
let firstTime = true;
function(){
    ... 
    if (firstTime) {
        firstTime = false;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what Javascript variables are for. You can make a variable, then test that against a condition in the function. Let me show you what I mean:

```js
window.timesRan = 0;

function bikeData() {
  //Check if the variable is > 1
  if (timesRan > 1) {
    return false;
  }
  //code here

  //then just add 1 to the variable every time
  timesRan += 1;
}
```

All the best, and I hope my answer works for you :)